# Refresh data in ListBox - stop moving the scrollbar and flashed selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, refresh, scrollbar

I try solve this problem. In WFP app I bind binadble collection to the property ItemSource of listBox.

Property signature is:

```
    public BindableCollection<UserInfo> Friends
    {
        get { return _friends; }
        set
        {
            _friends = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Friends);
        }
    }
```

UserInfo class consit property:

- BitmapImage ProfilePhoto {get;set;}
- String Nick{get;set}
- String Status{get;set;} //offline, online, chatting
- String ChatRoom{get;set;} //name of chat room where user chatting

I get every 10 seconds new fresh data as  IDictionary => ().

I need refresh data in listbox. So I try this:

```
    private void RefreshContactsData(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, UserInfo>> freshFriends)
    {
        //store selected item in listBox
        var tempSelectedFriend = SelectedFriend;

        //store selecte index in listbox
        var tempSelectedIndex = SelectedFriendsIndex;

        //Clear property which is binded on listBox ItemSource
        Friends.Clear();


        foreach (var freshFriend in freshFriends)
        {
            freshFriend.Value.IsFriend = true;

            //Add fresh data
            Friends.Add(freshFriend.Value);
        }

        StayInRoom();

        //set
        SelectedFriend = tempSelectedFriend;
        SelectedFriendsIndex = tempSelectedIndex;

    }
```

Problems is:

I store current current selected item in listBox, clear listbox, add new data, and set back selected item in listbox.
But user see that scrollbar is moved and moved back  and also selected item flashed.

How can I remove this unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the issue is your `SelectedFriend` property refers to a reference which no longer exists when your collection is repopulated.  Is there any property on UserInfo which uniquely identifies a user? (`Nick`?).  You could store this selected value instead, and then after repopulating the collection, find and set `SelectedFriend` to the item whose `Nick` matches the stored value.

Comment: No, SelectedFriedn exist in listBox. Problem cause that I clear items and add fresh value. I try youe way problem is still same.

Comment: As Zamboni mentions, a much better approach is to manipulate the BindableCollection that you already have by changing individual items.  If you are not happy adding INotifyPropertyChanged to your UserInfo model, then you could create a wrapper UserInfoViewModel which implements INPC, and make your collection of that type instead.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent listbox scrollbar jumping do not remove then add back all items from the BindableCollection.

Rewrite RefreshContactsData to:

1. Delete items that exist in Friends that no longer exist in freshFriends.
2. Add items that exist in freshFriends that do not exist in Friends.
3. Update existing items in Friends and freshFriends.

You may need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on UserInfo.